# getting the difference between the top of a container a clicked element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a container that has children inside it all with the same class.

I'm trying to get the difference between the clicked div and the top of the container then animate that clicked div to the top of the container.

I have gotten mixed results.. when it worked it would animate then reanimate the position of the container back to its original position.

Can anyone give me some insight into why this is not functioning correctly?

Code below.

```
    <style>
#contact-list-scroller {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: Silver;
    overflow:scroll;
    width: 200px;
}

#contact-list-scroller div {
    background: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid Gray;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative; width:150px; height:100vh;">
<div id="contact-list-scroller">
   <div class="test" id="contact_8965">stuff1</div>
   <div class="test" id="contact_8966">stuff2</div>
   <div class="test" id="contact_8967">stuff3</div>
   <div class="test" id="contact_8968">stuff4</div>
   <div class="test" id="contact_8969">stuff5</div>
   <div class="test"></div>
   <div class="test"></div>
   <div class="test"></div>
   <div class="test"></div>
   <div class="test"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('.test').click(function(){

var contactTopPosition = $(this).offsetTop;
var containerTop = $('#contact-list-scroller').scrollTop();
var heightDifference = containerTop - contactTopPosition;
console.log(contactTopPosition + ' contactTop');
console.log(containerTop + ' containerTop');
console.log(heightDifference + ' heightDifference');

//$("#contact-list-scroller").scrollTop(contactTopPosition);
$("#contact-list-scroller").animate({scrollTop: heightDifference,
    complete: $(this).unbind()
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: must it be a dynamical movement or can it be like a hard change? (with of without effect)

Comment: Dynamic movement based on what div is clicked (that div scrolls to the top of the container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason for giving every `<div>` inside of the container `class="test"`? If every child is a div, and has the same class, you can just use the *cascading* part of CCS, to target them. I also noticed you have a `$(this).unbind()` after the transition - you want each element to only be clickable once?

I've put together a snippet, assuming there's no specific need for the same class on all children, and commented out the `unbind()`. It uses `element.position().top` to find the visible distance between the element and its parent's top, then adds the parent's current scroll value.

```js
$('#contact-list-scroller > div').click(function() {

  var contactTopPosition = $(this).position().top;
  var contactList = $(this).parent();

  console.log(contactTopPosition + ' contactTop');

  contactList.animate({
    scrollTop: contactList.scrollTop() + contactTopPosition
    //, complete: $(this).unbind() // Stops the function from running again after the first click, is that waht you want?
  });
});
```

```css
#contact-list-scroller {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: Silver;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
}

#contact-list-scroller div {
  background: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid Gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position:relative; width:150px; height:100vh;">
  <div id="contact-list-scroller">
    <div id="contact_8965">stuff1</div>
    <div id="contact_8966">stuff2</div>
    <div id="contact_8967">stuff3</div>
    <div id="contact_8968">stuff4</div>
    <div id="contact_8969">stuff5</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you for the detailed explanation of why what i was doing was unsuccessful